# Getting all checkboxes that have been checked and then looping through them

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Ok, I have a situation where I have a page which has checkboxes on it next to items with input text fields.

I have a button at the top with the same fields of which the user can use to apply the settings to all the fields in the page that have been selected with their respective checkbox.

I'm trying to work out how to get all the checkboxes in the page that have been checked an then loop through them so I can possibly grab the ID for that row and then update the respective items, but I'm not 100% sure how to do this.

Each of the checkboxes on the page have the same class name, so I thought something like this would work..

```
var selected = $('input:checked', '.discount_select');
```

But it doesn't appear to work.

Here is a example checkbox and it's corresponding text box..

```
<input type="text" size="4" name="discount[101129]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="discount_select" name="select[101129]">
```

So basically I wanna loop through the found selectec checkboxes, hopefully be able to pull out the id `101129` somehow and then be able to update the textbox with that same id.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79udU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#apply_selected').click(function() {
    $('.discount_select:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).prev("input").val(this.name);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/79udU/1/

Edit: To actually apply the value from the top input, use this:

```
$('#apply_selected').click(function() {
    $('.discount_select:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).prev("input").val($("#apply_discount").val());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/79udU/2/

Comment: Didn't quite work, when I input `90` in the field at the top the text it put in the other fields was literally `select[101131]` for example.

Comment: @Brett -- What should it be, also what does the top field have to do with it? Thought this was simply looping over checked inputs and grabbing the ID attribute (which doesn't exist, that's why I used `name`)

Comment: It should be the value of whatever is placed into the field to the left of the `apply` button.

Comment: All of the inputs should contain that specified value? @Brett

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the `prev` selector? Like by referencing the name/id instead?

Comment: Not really, since `prev` is based off of `this` which targets the right `input` besides the checkbox.

Comment: Ok, cause there are actually 3 textboxes I need to target and didn't want to run into issues if I moved them around etc

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
var selected = $('input.discount_select:checked' );
```